# Ideas for better python process to check for data combination that meets requirements?

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I currently have my data table as the following (sample data):

| Role | Permission |
| --- | --- |
| Role 1 | A |
| Role 1 | B |
| Role 1 | C |
| Role 1 | D |
| Role 2 | C |
| Role 2 | D |
| Role 3 | E |
| Role 4 | F |
| Role … | … |

I want to find the combination of roles that returns the least permission percentage for the given set of permissions, where permission percentage is calculated from (distinct count of permission / total distinct permission)

For example, in the sample data we have 6 distinct permissions in total. Let’s say I want to have permission C and D. The role that returns least permission percentage is Role 2 (2/6 ~ 33%) while Role 1 meets my requirement as well, but Role 1 returns 4/6 ~ 66%.

In the real dataset, there are a lot more data and permission. I’m struggling with **How to best find the combination of roles required for each of the permission list specified that returns the least permission percentage?**

The dataset is on the Snowflake cloud where I can retrieve via python and do pandas data frame process that checks for each combination of role that meets the requirement. The thing is it takes long to run through the loop and I’m trying to optimize it or find a better way to process this.

Appreciate all your comments and thoughts. Thanks!

I checked every possible combination of roles and loop through it to find the combination that returns the least percentage, but it’s not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set operations with a [`powerset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))

s = df.groupby('Role')['Permission'].agg(set)
# Role
# Role 1    {A, B, C, D}
# Role 2          {C, D}
# Role 3             {E}
# Role 4             {F}
# Name: Permission, dtype: object

def find_combination(s, target):
    # optional: only keep rows with an intersection
    # this improves efficiency
    s = s[s & [target]]

    # get total number of permissions
    num_perm = len(set.union(*s))  # 6

    result = {}
    percent = 2
    for comb in powerset(s.index):
        # compute set union
        S = set.union(*s[list(comb)])
        # did we find a match? is it better than the previous match?
        if S.issuperset(target) and len(S)/num_perm < percent:
            result = set(comb)
            percent = len(S)/num_perm

    return result
```

Examples:

```
find_combination(s, {'C', 'D'})
# {'Role 2'}

find_combination(s, {'D', 'E'})
# {'Role 2', 'Role 3'}

find_combination(s, {'E', 'F'})
# {'Role 3', 'Role 4'}

find_combination(s, {'A', 'X'})
# {}

find_combination(s, {'B', 'D', 'E'})
# {'Role 1', 'Role 3'}

find_combination(s, {'D', 'E', 'F'})
# {'Role 2', 'Role 3', 'Role 4'}
```

Comment: This is very promising! I’m gonna test it out with the real dataset with a bit of adjustment. Thanks so much! :D

Comment: @PGS note that the code can be further optimized if you have a lot of Roles and Permissions. You could for example pre-filter the `s` to only keep the Roles that are the minimal superset of the target (i.e. if you have ABCDE and ABCD and the target is BC, you know you can drop ABCDE as ABCD will always be better). I didn't include such optimizations as it's out of the scope of the question and would clutter the code.

Comment: Thanks. That makes very much sense and I've already tried it with 16 roles that return possible combination of 65535. That took around a minute which it not so much different than my current solution. Will have to try and find a way to best optimize it then. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the combinations explode quickly, which is why I mentioned those possible optimizations. In fine this is a combinatorial problem, not always easy to solve efficiently ;)

Answer (score 0):

Filter only Role that have C and D

```
want = {'C', 'D'}
df1 = df.groupby(['Role']).filter(lambda x: set(x['Permission']) >= want)
```

`df1`

```
    Role    Permission
0   Role 1  A
1   Role 1  B
2   Role 1  C
3   Role 1  D
4   Role 2  C
5   Role 2  D
```

return Role 1 and Role 2

find minimal Role

```
df1.groupby('Role')['Permission'].nunique().idxmin()
```

output:

```
'Role 2'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea! Anyway there can be things like permission C and F, which requires more than one role. I believe this method can't handle that scenario?

Comment: This is possible by making the input dataset Catesian product of Roles.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: The problem in the text has been solved. With that, my mission is over. It is enough to give an idea to an additional question, and it is difficult to explain by making an example.

Comment: @PandaKim the problem isn't solved that easily, you didn't address the part on of the combinations of Roles. It's actually an interesting problem